# trigger - SQL Server 2008 - Msg 7391 - "no transaction is active/unable to begin trans"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trigger, oledb, msdtc

I have a trigger on my SQL Server, located in server7.

It inserts a data on another server (server5), after insert, as you see the code below:

```
CREATETRIGGER [dbo].[trgSPTInsereDepartamento]
   ON  [dbo].[tblDepartamento]
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into [Server5].alfabase.dbo.tblDepartamento (CodDepto,DescDepto,IncluiOutroDepto)
Select ins.codDepartamento, ins.DescDepartamento, 0
From inserted ins where not exists(select 1 from [Server5].alfabase.dbo.tblDepartamento sptsta where sptsta.CodDepto = ins.CodDepartamento)
END
```

When i make an insert, the SQL shows me this:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "server5"
> returned message   "No transaction is active.".
> Msg 7391, Level 16,
> State 2, Procedure trgSPTInsereDepartamento, Line 7 The operation
> could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked
> server "server5" was unable to begin a distributed
> transaction.

Local DTC properties is all checked ( it allows remote users ).

I've restarded the server and the DTC service. No Luck for me.

I read a lot of posts but none of them helped me.

Thanks for the help.

> **update1:**

Checked firewall. disabled it but still doesn't work.

DTC is ok ( only server5 is on a cluster. )

I'm really out of ideas guys.

Thank you very much.

> **Update 2**:

From server7 to server5, I have the problem above. To test, I made a trigger on a database from server4 to server5. and it worked. So, the problem is on server7.

Server7 is not on the Cluster (server3,4,5 are clustered).

Comment: Are both servers behind the same firewall?

Comment: hello. Well every SO has your firewall. but i've disabled it and still didn't work. So I presume it's not this the problem. Thank you very much DeadZone.

Comment: I know that you said that you disabled the firewall on server7, but [this MS Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306843) has some nice troubleshooting steps to look at, and not all of them are firewall specific.  A couple other ideas... Could Windows firewall have enabled when you disabled your firewall?  Also, I saw something (but can't find the link) about cloning a server.  Sometimes you need to uninstall MSDTC and reinstall it to get a new, unique ID.  You might want to try that.

Comment: Yes DeaDZone, for sure I will try. Thank you very much. I'm testing some triggers here. the results are:

server4 > server5 = OK
server5 > server7 = NO!
server7 > server5 = NO!

I will take a look at your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED!

Every site has the same step-by-step.

> - Start
> - DCOMCNFG
> - Expand "Component Services"
> - Expand "computers" >
> - Expand "My computer"
> - Expand "DTC"
> - right click on "Local DTC"
> - Properties
> - Security  check  "Network DTC Access" and " allow remote clientes".

It for sure will help a lot of people. The problem is that the server is in a cluster, so what a did is:

> - Start
> - DCOMCNFG
> - Expand "Component Services"
> - Expand "computers" >
> - Expand "My computer"
> - Expand "DTC"
> - **Expand "CLUSTERED DTCs" << This is the trick**
> - Right click on the server and make the same config as above for the "local DTC"

Restart service. Enjoy you boss Happy.

Answer (score 1):

We're also facing this issue & just resolved :)

We tried to link from MsSQL2008R2 (source) to MsSQL2019 (target). Both DB servers (VM) are located in the same domain - the 1st and 2nd ocate of the physical IP address same.

Before this, able to create the "linked server" at Source & Target servers.
We'd also used the same ID&password for authentication at both sides.
But hit error when tried to execute.

**Sharing, the things we'd done so far:**

1. Ensure the MSDTC Windows service is started successfully

**Service Name: Distributed Transaction Coordinator**

2. Ensure network & firewall connection (server's firewall also disabled) between Source & Target servers are OK.

At DOS, type this command to check:
**netstat -an | find "port no"**

3. Disable automatic 6to4 address generation.

Run these commands at DOS with admin rights:

**netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled**

**netsh interface 6to4 show state**

Do this at Source server only since it's SQL2008.

4. Update the C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc**hosts** and **lmhosts** files.

Did this at both Source & Target servers.

Not only I added the DB server's original hostname, but added the linked server label name (what you defined at SQL), in case unable to decipher properly.

For e.g.,

99.999.99.999 source

99.999.99.999 linkto_source

88.888.88.888 target

88.888.88.888 linkto_target

5. Run this at SQL to ensure the "**Ad Hoc Distributed Queries**" value is **1**

USE master;

GO

**EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1';**

**RECONFIGURE;**

GO

**EXEC sp_configure;**

6. Run this at SQL to ensure the "**SQLNCL10**" value under column "**allow_in_process**" is **1**

**EXEC master.sys.sp_MSset_oledb_prop;**

7. Check and configure these settings at **both Source & Target servers**

- From DOS, type **DCOMCNFG**
- Expand and select **Console Root -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> Distributed Transaction Coordinator -> Local DTC**
- Right click on **Local DTC** and select the **Properties** option
- Select the **Security** tab and do the below configurations:
- Network DTC Access -> checked
- Client and Administration - Allow Remote Clients -> **checked**
- Client and Administration - Allow Remote Administration -> **checked**
- Transaction Manager Communication - Allow inbound -> **checked**
- Transaction Manager Communication - Allow outbound -> **checked**
- Transaction Manager Communication - No authentication required -> **checked**
- Enable XA Transactions -> **unchecked**
- Enable SNA LU 6.2 Transactions -> **checked**
- DTC Logon account - Account -> **NT AUTHORITY\Network Service**

Hope the above helps :)